# AlpineJS refusing to act on native HTML event

Tags: javascript, video, event-handling, alpine.js

Here's my simple AlpineJS code -

```
<div x-data="{show: true}">

<video src="..." onended="show=false"></video>

</div>
```

I'm wondering why is this not working? No error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trying to use native JS with AlpineJS. Instead, use [`x-on`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on):

```html
<video x-on:ended="show=false">
```